# Anime with a girl in a kimono and a cloaked guy with a gunhand

Tags: story-identification, anime

I remember watching this one episode of an anime as a kid; I only remember bits and pieces.

There was a girl in a kimono who looked similar to Fuu from Samurai Champloo. She carried a hand gun because she was useless. There were two guys with her. One I can’t remember but the other guy was wearing a cloak I think and had a Gatling gun for one of his arms. They had to fight against a female demon I think?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your question could use some details; you should check out the [suggestions for a good anime ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/101407) to see if there are any additional details you can [edit] into your question.  For example, when did you watch this?  We have no idea when you were a kid.

Comment: This is really a shot in the dark, but could it be possibly *Sengoku BASARA Samurai Kings*? Though, the only similarity is due to [Nouhime wearing a kimono and wielding hand guns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lFC7OSpPt_0)

Answer (score 1):

Long shot, and a pretty broad trope, but could this be a very warped description of *Fullmetal Alchemist* (the 2003 one)? The gatling-hand guy be [Frank Archer](https://fma.fandom.com/wiki/Frank_Archer), a filler villain.

He at one point becomes a cyborg with a big gun in as part of his arm. I don't know of any girls with kimonos in the series, but I have not watched it or read much of the manga it is loosely based on.

[image: He's got a machine gun for an arm]

---

Found by looking for "gatling" in the anime/manga section of [Arm Cannon on TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ArmCannon). One entry said "A one shot videogame/Filler villain used an automail arm with a double barrel gattling gun..." about the show, so I looked the description up and found this.

Comment: I don't believe there are any kimonos in FMA2003.